# Within OnClickListener it gives - "The constructor ImageView(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined"?

Tags: android

Say I have this code, which creates an ImageView and puts it into a linearlayout.

Also I have an OnClick listener that's supposed to, upon click, remove the old imageview and replace it with a new one.

But strangely it shows "The constructor ImageView(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined".

```
final LinearLayout LinLayBtn = new LinearLayout(this);
ImageView ivBtn = new ImageView(this);
ivBtn = mkatt.makeKey( ivBtn, btnHue, btnSat, buttonScale, buttonScaleCnt, textAdjust, btnTextColor, buttonText, btnOpa, spacingLR, spacingTB);
LinLayBtn.addView(ivBtn);

LinLayBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        LinLayBtn.removeAllViews();
        ImageView ivBtn = new ImageView(this); // The constructor ImageView(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined
        ivBtn = mkatt.makeKey( ivBtn, btnHue, btnSat, buttonScale, buttonScaleCnt, textAdjust, btnTextColor, buttonText, btnOpa, spacingLR, spacingTB);
        LinLayBtn.addView(ivBtn);

    }
   });
```

Any ideas what to do with it?

Thanks!

Comment: Warning: you are defining `ivBtn` twice. Once as field and second as a local variable inside `onClick()` method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`this` in the ImageView constructor is the OnClickListener instance.  You need to pass it the instance of your Activity class (i.e. the outer class).  Say your outer class is called `MyActivity`, then you should pass `MyActivity.this` to the ImageView constructor